Parameterized query when binding paged Datalist
I am populating a paged Datalist (=dlProducts). I want to parameterize my SQL query (to limit the opportunity for SQL injection; as 'strCategory' comes from the querystring). However, I have been unable to figure out how or find another resource to help.
        public void bindDlProducts(string strCategory)
        {
            string strSql = "SELECT productId, item_id, price, units FROM Products prod, Categories cat WHERE cat.categoryID = prod.categoryID AND prod.active = 1 AND cat.CategoryName = '" + strCategory + "';";

            dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, connstring);
            dset = new DataSet();
            adsource = new PagedDataSource();
            dadapter.Fill(dset);
            adsource.DataSource = dset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            adsource.PageSize = 9;
            adsource.AllowPaging = true;
            adsource.CurrentPageIndex = pos;
            btnfirst.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
            btnprevious.Enabled = !adsource.IsFirstPage;
            btnlast.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;
            btnnext.Enabled = !adsource.IsLastPage;

            dlProducts.DataSource = adsource;
            dlProducts.DataBind();
        }


But don't use AddWithValue c.f. https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
